# error while loading mp3 files to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I want to add one mp3 file into mongodb database using gridfs.my mp3 file is located on my desktop.So i m using the command i.e

" C:\mongodb\bin\mongofiles.exe -d gridfs put C:\Users\27390\Desktop\Kalimba.mp3"

but its showing the following error i.e " stntax error-unexpected token illegal"

please suggest me something.

Comment: anyone having any idea kindly reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include mongodb/bin in your PATH. Navigate to the directory which contains the file and then key in the command:

```
mongofiles.exe -d gridfs put Kalimba.mp3
```